# Tkinter: 'str' object has no attribute 'children' when attempting to close

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I'm trying to learn tkinter gui in python 3.7, I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
# Configuración de la ventana principal
root=Tk()
root.title("Cath Config")


#Definición de clases
#Frames
class marco(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, color="#F3F3F3", ancho="1024", alto="680", borde="5", tipoborde="groove"):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master=master
        self.config(bg=color,width=ancho,height=alto,bd=borde,relief=tipoborde)
    self.pack()


#Configuración del widget frame
mainframe1=marco(master="root")

#Ejecución de la ventana principal
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is the code "works", when I run that code it shows the root with the main frame without problem, but when i attempt to close the root, it does not closes and throws this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\konoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\konoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2061, in destroy
for c in list(self.children.values()): c.destroy()
  File "C:\Users\konoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2306, in destroy
if self._name in self.master.children:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'children'
```

Comment: Try `Frame.__init__(self, master)`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've passed a string as the value of the `master` parameter. That parameter must be a widget, not a string.

```
mainframe1=marco(master=root)
```

You should also pass that parameter to the `__init__` method:

```
Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

Strictly speaking, it's not necessary for this specific code, since the default for the master is the root window. However, if you're going to create a subclass of `Frame` you should always include the master in the constructor so that the widget can be used in places other than the root window.

Answer (score -1):

One way to handle this is bind the key with the action:

```
def quit(event):
    print "you pressed control c"
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Control-c>', quit)
root.mainloop()
```

Another way would be to but a Quit button to safely close the Tkinter window.

```
root=Tk()
root.title("Cath Config")
Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit).pack()

def quit():
    global root
    root.quit()
```